# Laravel Nova Multiple Resource Creation

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I want to create multiple `Item` resource base on the quantity field specified by the user.

I've been searching for hours and no solution found. My resource field is simple with only one field which is the quantity.

```php
public function fields()
{
    return [
        Text::make('quantity')
            ->rules('required', 'integer'),
    ];
}
```

When I do create the resource, I expect to create multiple database records base on the quantity value. Is it possible with laravel nova?

Answer (score 0):

You must override the model record creation method:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events-using-closures

```
protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($user) {
            //
        });
    }
```